# Entity Framework using Stored Procedure - needs help

Tags: .net, entity-framework

i am using VS2008 3.5 framework.

I'm attempting to use the Entity Framework for data access, but I'm
running into a few issues with stored procedures.

I imported this stored procedure into the framework diagram and then
made it a function import but i dont see my stored procedure

```
        using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities ())
        {
            foreach (Basic visit in context.) //<<< i dont see the SP here?
            {
                                 }
        }
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a return type. This happens often if there is no return type.

You can just create a dummy entity named ReturnHelper with one scalar value "return" as Int32 and use in in your function import as scalar output. This should do the trick :-)

Howtos:
http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values

http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/20/entity-framework-40-scalar-and-void-functions

Comment: will you show me the steps to do as i am new to EF and never done this before. - thanks.

Comment: You can find a good explanation here:
http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values
and here:
http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/20/entity-framework-40-scalar-and-void-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502129/entity-framework-doesnt-work-with-stored-procedures), for example.