# EDMX and stored procedures; I can't see a method to call my SPROC in the context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I added a SPROC to my EDMX using the update model option. 
I then did a function import and assigned it a null return type.
The problem is when I try to call the SPROC from myContext.Current, there is no sign of it. 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using EF v4? This was not possible in EF v1, see, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502129/entity-framework-doesnt-work-with-stored-procedures).